# Samsung 633-NW monitor flashing after upgrade to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a computer with a Samsung SyncMaster 633 NW and Windows XP.

Now I updated my OS to Windows 7 32-bit. My driver CD was not compatible with it. When I selected the screen resolution, my monitor's name was SyncMaster and recommended resolution was 1360x768.

After some days, when I started my computer, the screen was flashing. I once more opened screen resolution settings, and my monitor name changed to "Generic Non-PnP". Changing the resolution didn't solve my problem.

When I boot into Ubuntu, the same problem occurs. The screen starts to flicker.

What to do? When  I checked the monitor drivers, it showed "Device is not working properly" and location *on NVIDIA GeForce 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM)*.